# Можно ли реализовать одномерный jagged массив, с двумерными массивами в нем?

Tags: c#, массивы

Можно ли реализовать одномерный jagged массив, с двумерными массивами в нем? и как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Точно так же, как и любой другой jagged массив:

```
int[][,] m = new int[5][,];
for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++)
{
    m[i] = new int[2, 3];
}
```